# PS3 Sixaxis controller won't charge over USB

Tags: usb, controller

I made a 5V charging setup and want to connect USB devices to it to charge them. Most devices work ok, but my Playstation 3 Sixaxis controllers won't charge. The voltage is ok, slightly over 5V. As prescribed by USB I short circuited both data wires to indicate to the devices that there is no data connection and they can draw high currents (1.8A). I also connected the cable's shield to the ground, which should be done on the host side. Apparently the Sixaxis controller wants to do some kind of handshaking before it wants to charge, because the only devices that will charge them are the PS3 itself and computers. I hope to hear from someone who successfully made a setup to charge the controllers. Dedicated chargers like that exist on the market.

Comment: I'm at work so I can't check this link, but it could be of use: http://forums.ps2dev.org/viewtopic.php?t=12778&highlight=charging+ps3+controller&sid=a8b990ca43a70447780b344b793fd3da. Source of this link here: http://richardappleby.wordpress.com/2010/12/24/when-is-a-usb-charger-not-a-usb-charger/

Comment: I see why this got close votes, but on inspection the user is attempting to make their own charger, at least to me this seems this is design related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PS3 wireless controller won't change on simple wall chargers, even when using any combination of resistor signaling on the D+/D- pins. This is unlike Apple iPhones or Samsung phones or similar, which do use resistor voltage dividers to signal if it is a computer or weak charger or high capacity charger.

Sony has effectively made it so that only authorized chargers, or computers can charge the Sixaxis. This is done through enumeration of the usb connection.

This could be emulated through a [microcontroller acting as a usb host](http://forums.ps2dev.org/viewtopic.php?t=12778&highlight=charging%20ps3%20controller&sid=a8b990ca43a70447780b344b793fd3da) (Attiny running V-USB), as @Shamtam has linked to in the comments.

See: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73919/what-wall-plug-chargers-can-be-used-to-charge-ps3-controllers